# Value of type "JqueryStatic" is not callable

Tags: jquery, typescript

I am developing a typescript project. When I call "$" editor says "Value of type 'JqueryStatic' is not callable.". I installed jquery.definetelyTyped package and I also referenced jquery.d.ts file.

[image]

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013, TypeScript 1.4 and jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped version 2.1.7 - and it works fine. If you are using the latest version of the type definition, it relies on features of TypeScript 1.4.

Comment: I also using typescript 1.4 and jquery. Typescript.DefinetelyTyped version is 2.1.7 but it gives compile error but it works fine in runtime :)

Answer (score 23):

Resharper 9.0 does not support the new union types which have just arrived in TypeScript, and which have appeared in jquery.d.ts in the last few releases.

Resharper 9.1 [supports Typescript unions](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/04/21/typescript-and-ecmascript-6-in-resharper-9-1/), so it fixes this.

If you can't update, do this in your nuget console:

```
uninstall-package jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped -force
install-package jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped -version 2.1.4
```

Comment: I didn't know how to get to the NuGet Console.

In Visual Studio 2013
Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 1):

This may help in visual code:

```
import myJq from "jquery";
window.jQuery = window.$ =  myJq;
```

tsconfig is below:

```
 "module": "esnext"
```