# Value of type “jQueryStatic<TElement extends Node>” is not callable

Tags: jquery, typescript, visual-studio-2017, resharper, definitelytyped

**Issue:**
Visual Studio IntelliSense yells at `$`: `Value of type “jQueryStatic<TElement extends Node>” is not callable`

**Example code** (All instances of `$`, really):

```
const emaildiv = $("<div>", { "class": "email-item" });
$(containerid).append(emaildiv);
```

**Setup:**

- Visual Studio 2017
- ASP.NET Core Web Application
- [DefinitelyTyped jquery 3.2.1](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts)
- jquery 3.2.1
- ts 2.3
- Resharper 2017.1.3

tsconfig.ts:

```
 {
   "compilerOptions": {
     "lib": [ "es2015", "es2015.iterable", "dom" ],
     "noImplicitAny": true,
     "noEmitOnError": true,
     "removeComments": false,
     "sourceMap": true,
     "target": "es5"
   },
   "files": [
     // a bunch of local files...
   ],
   "compileOnSave": true
 }
```

.csproj:

```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
     <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.3</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
   </ItemGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
     <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
   </ItemGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
     <!-- other .ts files -->
     <TypeScriptCompile Include="Scripts\Scripts.ts" />
   </ItemGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
     <Folder Include="wwwroot\scripts\" />
   </ItemGroup>

 </Project>
```

Everything builds and works fine. Anyone has any clue?

Comment: There is no call in your sample code of `$`.  There must at least be some parentheses or something somewhere.  Please provide more context.

Comment: @recursive Example code added. All instances of '$'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out the issue is with Resharper again ([Value of type "JqueryStatic" is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148329/value-of-type-jquerystatic-is-not-callable)). Here's a list of everything I did:

- Update TypeScript and jquery.d.ts per [basarat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390330/basarat)'s answer
- Update Resharper to 2017.2 (i.e. the latest version)
- ReSharper → Options → General → Clean caches ([ReSharper TypeScript seems to be not working at all in my VS 2015 installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860096/resharper-typescript-seems-to-be-not-working-at-all-in-my-vs-2015-installation))
- ReSharper → Options → Code Editing → TypeScript → Inspections → TypeScript language level - latest available
- Restart Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

> Value of type “jQueryStatic” is not callable

Caused by compatability issues between the type definiton and typescript compiler version.

## Fix

Upgrade to typescript latest (`2.5.2`) and make sure `jquery.d.ts` (or `@types/jquery`) are up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Moved the csproj to 2.5.2 and resynced the types definition. Still the same issue.